# How to style specific polygons from a geojson with Leaflet

Tags: javascript, leaflet, json

I have a World Countries geojson, that has country codes as "ID" (feature.id) and names as feature.properties.name

I would like to color specific countries for making a "countries visited" map.

What would be the easiest way to provide a list of ids or names to assign a color to them?

Currently my code for one country is this:

```
 var map = L.map('map').setView([30.45,24.61], 3);
 function style(feature) {
        if ("Latvia" == feature.properties.name) {
            return {
                weight: 2,
                opacity: 1,
                color: 'white',
                dashArray: '3',
                fillOpacity: 0.7,
                fillColor: '#FFA000'
            };
        } else {
            return {
                weight: 2,
                opacity: 1,
                color: 'white',
                dashArray: '3',
                fillOpacity: 0.7,
                fillColor: '#000'
            };
        }
    }

var geojsonLayer = new L.GeoJSON.AJAX("countries.geo.json", {
            style: style
        });       

geojsonLayer.addTo(map);
```

I would like to replace the "IF" thing with some sort of comma separated list of ids or names.

Here is a sample of that geojson file:

```
{"type":"FeatureCollection","features":[
{"type":"Feature","id":"AFG","properties":{"name":"Afghanistan"},"geometry":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":
```

Comment: Is it possible to add a color attribute in your GeoJSON for each country? In Openlayers, you can use data form the GeoJSON to modify the style in a StyleMap. I do not know Leaflet but it probably has something similar

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the [Leaflet Polygon](http://leafletjs.com/examples/geojson.html) examples, here is one way with a Switch Statement:

```
var states = [{
"type": "Feature",
"properties": {"party": "Republican"},
"geometry": {
    "type": "Polygon",
    "coordinates": [[
        [-104.05, 48.99],
        [-97.22,  48.98],
        [-96.58,  45.94],
        [-104.03, 45.94],
        [-104.05, 48.99]
    ]]
}
}, {
"type": "Feature",
"properties": {"party": "Democrat"},
"geometry": {
    "type": "Polygon",
    "coordinates": [[
        [-109.05, 41.00],
        [-102.06, 40.99],
        [-102.03, 36.99],
        [-109.04, 36.99],
        [-109.05, 41.00]
    ]]
}
}];

L.geoJson(states, {
style: function(feature) {
    switch (feature.properties.party) {
        case 'Republican': return {color: "#ff0000"};
        case 'Democrat':   return {color: "#0000ff"};
    }
}
}).addTo(map);
```